# Behavior of STRING verb

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am reading a COBOL program file and I am struggling to understand the way the `STRING` command works in the following example

```
STRING  WK-NO-EMP-SGE                              
   ','                                         
   WK-DT-DEB-PER-FEU-TEM                       
   ','                                       
   WK-DT-FIN-PER-FEU-TEM                     
DELIMITED  BY  SIZE                           
INTO  UUUUUU-CO-CLE-ERR-DB2
```

I have three possible understandings of what it does:

1. Either the code concatenate each variables into `UUUUUU-CO-CLE-ERR-DB2` and separate each values with `','`, and the last variable is delimited by size;
2. Either the code concatenate each variables into `UUUUUU-CO-CLE-ERR-DB2` and separate each values with `','`, but all the values are delimited by size (meaning that the `DELIMITED BY SIZE` in this case applies to all the values passed in the string command;
3. Or each variable is delimited by a specific character, for example `WK-NO-EMP-SGE` would be delimited by `','`, `WK-DT-DEB-PER-FEU-TEM` by `','` and `WK-DT-FIN-PER-FEU-TEM` would then be `DELIMITED BY SIZE`.

Which of my reading is actually the good one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the syntax-diagram for STRING (from the *Enterprise COBOL Language Reference*):

[image: Syntax Diagram]

Now you need to know how to read it.

Fortunately, the same document tells you how:

> How to read the syntax diagrams
>
> Use the following description to read the syntax diagrams in this
>   document:
>
> . Read the syntax diagrams from left to right, from top to bottom,
>   following the path of the line.
>
> The >>--- symbol indicates the beginning of a syntax diagram.
>
> The ---> symbol indicates that the syntax diagram is continued on the
>   next line.
>
> The >--- symbol indicates that the syntax diagram is continued from
>   the previous line.
>
> The --->< symbol indicates the end of a syntax diagram. Diagrams of
>   syntactical units other than complete statements start with the >---
>   symbol and end with the ---> symbol.
>
> . Required items appear on the horizontal line (the main path).
>
> . Optional items appear below the main path.
>
> . When you can choose from two or more items, they appear vertically,
>   in a stack.
>
> If you must choose one of the items, one item of the stack appears on
>   the main path.
>
> If choosing one of the items is optional, the entire stack appears
>   below the main path.
>
> . An arrow returning to the left above the main line indicates an item
>   that can be repeated.
>
> A repeat arrow above a stack indicates that you can make more than one
>   choice from the stacked items, or repeat a single choice.
>
> . Variables appear in italic lowercase letters (for example, parmx).
>   They represent user-supplied names or values.
>
> . If punctuation marks, parentheses, arithmetic operators, or other
>   such symbols are shown, they must be entered as part of the syntax.

All that means, if you follow it through, that your number 2 is correct.

You can use a delimiter (when you don't have fixed-length data) or just use the size. Any item which is not explicit in how it is delimited, is delimited by the next `DELIMITED BY` statement.

One thing to watch for with STRING, which doesn't matter in your case, is that the target field does not get space-padded if the data is shorter than the target. With variable-length data, you need to clear the field to space before the STRING executes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nuance one must grasp in order to understand the results.  DELIMITED BY SIZE can be misleading if one has experience in other programming languages.

Each of the three variables has a size that is defined in WORKING-STORAGE.  Let's presume it looks something like this.

```
05 WK-NO-EMP-SGE PIC X(04).
05 WK-DT-DEB-PER-FEU-TEM PIC X(10).
05 WK-DT-FIN-PER-FEU-TEM PIC X(10).
```

If the value of the variables were set like this:

```
MOVE 'BOB' TO WK-NO-EMP-SGE.
MOVE 'Q' TO WK-DT-DEB-PER-FEU-TEM.
MOVE 'D19EIEIO2B' TO WK-DT-FIN-PER-FEU-TEM.
```

Then one might expect the value of UUUUUU-CO-CLE-ERR-DB2 to be:

```
BOB,Q,D19EIEIO2B
```

But it would actually be:

```
BOB ,Q         ,D19EIEIO2B
```

Comment: But the "value of the variables" can not be like that for the first two. They are "BOBb" and "Qbbbbbbbbb", where b represents a blank. So what do you find misleading? That COBOL does not have "strings"? That COBOL has fixed-length fields (except for the variable-length ones) is not limited to STRING, it is the way it is.

Comment: @BillWoodger True that the `"value(s) of the variables"` are `"BOBb" and "Qbbbbbbbbb"`, But that is not the same as `"value of the variables were set like this"`. The value of `WK-NO-EMP-SGE` can **be set** as 'BOB', and then the value of `WK-NO-EMP-SGE` will be 'BOBb'. Can definitely be misleading to many new COBOL developers who've never worked with fixed-length fields. I've seen many, not only with COBOL.